# Cannot download keystore or JSON files when creating MY ether wallet

Tags: wallets, ether

I'm new to all cryto currencies.
 My question is. when I downloaded "MY Ether Wallet" 
I printed the wallet just fine. saved the public and private keys
and tried to download the json and the keystore files nothing happened
I tried multiple times to click the unresponsive buttons. Result
No keystore or json download.

The Wallet opened successfully.
Currently no funds are deposited.

Any help to get these file appreciated .

Thank you. jpmiller

Comment: Won't download for me on Chrome either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keystore directory stores the accounts that you create. So, I don't understand what you meant by downloading keystore files. Perhaps you need to read about creating accounts. If you have already done that, this information (along with all other blockchain data) is stored in the following folder by default:

> Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum
>
> Linux: ~/.ethereum
>
> Windows: %APPDATA%\Ethereum

[Source](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore)

Answer (score 1):

Try using chrome instead of Safari . I had the same issue, I used chrome and it download the key right away.